# echosign combinedDocument api

Tags: node.js, buffer, encode, fs, echosign

https://api.na1.echosign.com/api/rest/v5/agreements/{agreementId}/combinedDocument

I am trying to create a file from the body of the response, but it is creating a file that I can't open. It requires a password even though there isn't one on the file. I think this must have something to do with the encoding / decoding.

I am using a node express server. Here are the few lines of code I am using:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    baseUrl: 'https://api.na1.echosign.com/api/rest/v5',
    url: '/agreements/' + req.params.id + '/combinedDocument',
    headers: {'Access-Token': process.env.ECHOSIGN_INTEGRATIONKEY}
  },
  function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
      res.send(error);
    }
    else {
      var buf = new Buffer(body)
      res.set({
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf',
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8'
       });
       res.write(buf);
       res.end();
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working in the end in case somebody else stumbles across this. I think the problem was that the data being returned from the API is a stream and it needed to have the chunking logic and then get concatenated in order to avoid getting corrupted.

Also included is encoding to base64, pushing it into a database and then getting it back, decoding it and pushing it to the browser. I wasn't going to leave it like that, but had it set up that way to test the full cycle.

```
router.get('/echosign/agreement/:id', function(req, res) {
  if (req.user !== 'myUserId') {
    console.log(req.user);
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {

    var request = require('request');
    var data = [];

    request({
      baseUrl: 'https://api.na1.echosign.com/api/rest/v5',
      url: '/agreements/' + req.params.id + '/combinedDocument',
      headers: {'Access-Token': process.env.ECHOSIGN_INTEGRATIONKEY}
    }).on('data', function(chunk){
        data.push(chunk);
      })
      .on('end', function(){
        data = Buffer.concat(data).toString('base64');

        client.connect(function(err) {
          if(err) {
            return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
          }
          client.query("UPDATE agreements SET file = '" + data + "' WHERE agreementid = '" + req.params.id + "' RETURNING agreement, file", function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
              return console.log(result, err);
            }
            client.end();
            res.set({
              'Content-Type': 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8',
              'Content-Disposition': "inline; filename='" + result.rows[0].agreement.name + ".pdf'"
            });
            res.send(new Buffer(result.rows[0].file, 'base64'));
          });
        });
      });
    }
});
```